# How to add exception to iptables?

Tags: linux, unix, iptables, rhel

I'm working on a RHEL server and I need to add an **exception** in the firewall, so you can allways axcess on **Port 3000**...

How can I do this?

---

Thanks @[Rahul R Dhobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184706/rahul-r-dhobi):

`-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT`

I have added this after my other rules, but I only get an error,

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 13 failed
                                                           [FAILED]
```

when restarting the service. As I'm really new to Linux/iptables, I can't really tell, if it's a syntax Error, or something else.

I also tried

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I don't get an Error anymore, but I still can't access through port 3000.

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open flle /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Append rule as follows:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Restart iptables service

```
# service iptables restart
```

Verify connection on port

```
netstat -a | grep 3000
```

Comment: I have Edited my question, in reply to your answer.

Comment: iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 13 failed
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Provide /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: Maybe It's a problem with tcp? I want to access the server through a usual web-browser.